# Is there a (preferably free) Visual Studio extension which remembers what files I had open based on the git branch I'm working in?

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

That would be really cool for maintaining context when I switch branches - say, if I'm working in the FeatureA branch and open File1.cs and File2.xaml, then switch to the BugB branch, then those two files would be closed, but then when I switch back to FeatureA then the files would be reopened. That way I can make the computer keep track of what I was working on, rather than having my brain do it! :)